# Rails 3.2 jRuby deployment on Glassfish fails

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, glassfish

even a new generated RoR application without any controllers/models does not start on Glassfish (Version 3.1.2.2 runs on Ubuntu). My development environment: Windows8, jRuby 1.7.4). Java Upgrades to 1.7.0_40 in both environments did not solve the problem.

I use the Warbler gem to generate the war-file.

The problem in the production environment:

org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) Exception loading extension KryptcoreService: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream handler unavailable due to: null

Comment: It's always wise to put everything needed to respond to a question _in the question_. What is the error? Many people won't want to follow your link. Also, as soon as you fix the problem the content of your question becomes obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the error using an older jruby-openssl gem version